# Как выбрать, какой пост по номеру я хочу взять при использовании произвольных полей wp с помощью php?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, backend, acf

Собственно, вот такой быдло код

```
<div class="container novosti">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            $recent = new WP_Query(array( 
                'post_type' => "quite_news",

                ));
            $real_count=wp_count_posts("quite_news")->publish;
            $count = 0;

            while ($count < 9 ) {
                $recent->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="novost" onclick="return location.href = '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
                        <span><?php the_time('d.m'); ?></span>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $count++; ?>
            <?php } wp_reset_query();?>
        </div> <?php  ?>
        <div class="container row nav">
            <ul>
                <?php for ($nomber=1; $nomber <= intdiv($real_count, 9) + 1; $nomber++) { ?>
                    <li><a href=quite_news.php?var=val&xxx=yyy><?php echo $nomber; ?></a></li><?php
                } ?>                

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Мне необходимо по клику на кнопку убирать одну часть записей, и заменять более новыми, притом количество записей всегда остаётся неизвестным и условно бесконечным. Изначально хотел сделать через AJAX, но застрял даже на этом этапе. Буду рад, если ещё и скинет кто литературу по реализации подобного без перезагрузки, ибо не до конца понимаю как передавать данные из пхп в яваскрипт и как они вообще храняться в пхп, когда он запрашивает их с сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее, на мой взгляд, [руководство по AJAX в WordPRess на русском](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

Когда js инициирует ajax-запрос, производится частичная инициализация WordPress, и управление передается пользовательскому обработчику - функции, которую обычно помещают в functions.php темы. Функция проделывает необходимую работу, делает вывод "на экран" требуемой информации и завершает свою работу (обязательно!) через die(). Весь буфер вывода на экран после этого передаётся в js, где с ним продолжают работать - выводят в нужный div на текущей странице или обрабатывают иным образом.

Лучше, конечно, передавать результат работы php обработчика ajax через json, используя для этого функции wp_send_json_success() или wp_send_json_error().